# Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[[System.Decimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, azure, azure-sql-database

In my webApi2 service I am using Entity framework as my orm with Linq as query language backend as azure-sql.
My DTO class to map my query results.

```
public class RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO
{
    public List<int> L1 { get; set; }
    public List<int> L2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> L3 { get; set; }

    public RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO()
    {

        L1 = new List<int>();

        L2 = new List<int>();
        L3 = new List<int>();

    }
}
```

My query to fill data.

```
var leveZones =  (from s in db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap
                        group s by s.Level_no
                        into g
                        select new RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO
                        {
                            L1 = (g.Key == 1) ? (List<int>)g: convertedLocationArray,
                            L2 = (g.Key == 2) ? (List<int>)g : convertedLocationArray,
                            L3 = (g.Key == 3) ? (List<int>)g : convertedLocationArray

                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Above query fetches zoneids which belongs to particular level(only 3 fixed levels are there in my database as shown in below image)

[image]

After executing my code i was catch with an exception with message saying

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping2[[System.Decimal,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[RTLSWebService.Models.RTLS_DB.RTLS_SpotLevelMap,
>   RTLSWebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types.

Comment: `g` is of type `IGrouping<decimal, RTLS_SpotLevelMap>` and you are trying to cast it to `List<int>`, the error is fairly self explanatory.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand? `g` is an `IGrouping`. You probably just want the elements, so just add something like `.ToList()` to get rid of the Key and turn it into a List. One more thing: you might want to rethink the datatypes in your database. Decimal seems off for an ID.

Comment: Down voters, kindly specify reasons for down-voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?:

```
var lookup = db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap.ToLookup(s => s.Level_no, s => s.ZoneId);
new RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO
{
    L1 = lookup[1].ToList(),
    L2 = lookup[2].ToList(),
    L3 = lookup[3].ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var leveZones =  (from s in db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap
                    group s by s.Level_no
                    into g
                    select new RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO
                    {
                        L1 = (g.Key == 1) ? g.ToList(): convertedLocationArray,
                        L2 = (g.Key == 2) ? g.ToList() : convertedLocationArray,
                        L3 = (g.Key == 3) ? g.ToList() : convertedLocationArray

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I already tried it is giving compile time error as " type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between ...."

Comment: what is : convertedLocationArray? What is schema for RTLS_SpotLevelMap ?

Comment: convertedLocationArray is an empty array and RTLS_SpotLevelMap schema is              " create table RTLS_SpotLevelMap(zone_id numeric(10) NOT NULL,Level_no numeric(3) not null)  "

Comment: Thanks for you help @Piotr I had done it through another method.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you made it;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution by making individual query for each list.

```
  var levelZones = new RTLSLevelZonesInfoDTO();

  var l1 = await ((db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap.Where(p => p.Level_no == 1)).Select(q => (int)q.zone_id)).ToListAsync();
  var l2 = await ((db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap.Where(p => p.Level_no == 2)).Select(q => (int)q.zone_id)).ToListAsync();
                        var l3 = await ((db.RTLS_SpotLevelMap.Where(p => p.Level_no == 3)).Select(q => (int)q.zone_id)).ToListAsync();

  levelZones.L1 = l1;
  levelZones.L2 = l2;
  levelZones.L3 = l3;
```